# How to offload geography operation to SQL Server in Entity Framework Core 1.0

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, spatial, entity-framework-core

How to consume geography data stored in SQL Server using Entity Framework Core if geography data type is not yet supported and stored procedures too?

Comment: For the moment, you should use EF6 if you plan to release your application. There is no date for a final release....

Comment: @Thomas not always an option, for example if targeting UWP

Comment: ohh... sorry ^^ did you see this issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1100?

Comment: Yes, actually, the last post with such question there was written by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i've done it. Obviously you don't get the features of the DbGeography type, but for simple queries it should suffice.

```
  public async Task<List<PointOfInterest>> Execute(double latitude, double longitude, int radius)
        {
            return await this.context.PointsOfInterest.FromSql(

            "DECLARE @point geography = geography::Point(@p0, @p1, 4326); " +

            "SELECT Id, DateAdded, Latitude, Longitude " +
            "FROM dbo.PointsOfInterest " +
            "WHERE @point.STDistance(Location) <= @p2",
            longitude,
             latitude,
            radius).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: How do you map your property 'Location'?
Location is a sys.geography in your database right, but how did you declare it in your model / fluent api?
I have a similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873740/entity-framework-core-type-udt-is-not-supported-on-this-platform/

Comment: I think i just had it mapped in my model as a string, and then added a migration to Alter the column to a Geography type using the builder.Sql() method. Any query/command that you do with that field will need to be in Raw SQL.

Comment: @Eli See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765439/efcore-spatial-query-a-number-is-expected-at-position-9-of-the-input-the-input/40877869#40877869